Will I have enough time to connect between Paris Gare du Nord and Gare de l’Est accounting for any passport control?
Hi there—two of us are traveling from London St. Pancras to Paris on the Eurostar the morning of Dec. 24, arriving at Gare du Nord at 9:20am. We have a connection (OUIGO) at Gare de l’Est departing at 10:08am for Strasbourg.
Do we need to worry about not having enough time in Paris to clear any customs / passport control before boarding the train to Strasbourg? I know it’s a short 5-10 walk between Gare du Nord and Gare de l’Est—mainly just want to make sure there isn’t additional time we need to be accounting for for any passport / visa checks. Some sources on the internet say all such checks would happen in London, but want to confirm there wouldn’t be any issues in Paris time-wise, given that we’d have less than an hour between trains.
For context, one of us has an American passport and the other has an Indian one (with a valid Schengen visa).

Keep in mind that if the Eurostar arrives late, you will miss your OUIGO train. Depending on how you bought the ticket, this could mean that you have to buy a ticket for the next OUIGO train at your own expense. Better plan your connections with enough time buffer to compensate for any delays.

@scai that is not correct. Both Eurostar and OUIGO as part of SNCF are members of Railteam, meaning they are committed to HOTNAT - Hop On The Next Available Train. Paris Nord and Paris Est count as a single transit station in this case. So should OP miss their connection they can request to board the next available OUIGO train from Paris Est.

About boarding time: I routinely take TGV trains from Paris, I arrive to the platform 3 minutes before departure, and I make it to the train.

@pts : what kind of TGV are you talking about? Inoui, or Ouigo?

@YPOC does Ouigo really count as being part of SNCF for HOTNAT? This information seems hard to find. I do find some indications that this might indeed be the case. Namely, the Railteam website does in principle list Ouigo under the SNCF general heading. However, it does not include an explicit assurance that Ouigo is covered under HOTNAT. If you can find a source that says so explicitly, I would be happy to see it!

Also an interesting question: if they do honour HOTNAT, would they accept to put you on a different kind of train from the one originally booked? The next train to Strasbourg is actually an ICE, leaving at 10:54. The next TGV to Strasbourg is at 12:46. The next actual Ouigo to Strasbourg is not until 16:16...

Thank you everyone for the thoughtful responses — you guys are the best. It’s my first time using Stack Exchange and you all did not disappoint :)

We ended up switching our train to Paris to the prior day to have a bit of time to explore there before heading to Strasbourg + to have peace of mind about not missing any transfers given the holiday / winter season. Thank you so very much everyone for all of the advice here. We would have felt comfortable going through with our original itinerary based on all the feedback!

All formalities indeed happen in London, this won't have any impact on your transfer. In Paris you just walk to the end of the platform like you would from any other train, only difference is that there are guards at the end to prevent anybody from walking towards the platform and circumventing the boarding process in the other direction (to London). There are also large glass doors to close off the platform once everybody has left the train.
When you reach the end of the platform, turn left, and walk all the way, gare de l'Est is on the other side of the station (I guess there should be signage but I don't really pay attention as I know it very well).

Thank you! And it seems like for a domestic train within France to Strasbourg, there really wouldn’t be anything other than a train ticket check upon or after boarding yeah? Really want to avoid buying a new ticket to Strasbourg if there’s any risk at all with the transfer—I appreciate your guidance as it’s my first time going to Europe!

At gare de l'Est (and most other stations in Paris), you should expect a gate controlling access to the platform, you'll need to scan your ticket before getting on the platform. If it doesn't work, staff is available for a manual check.

Sorry, I just noticed you mentioned you have a Ouigo train, did you check what the ticket says regarding boarding? It's a low-cost train with slightly different rules, I don't have any experience with those.

So it says the tickets are still being prepared and will be sent a few days before the journey date. It seems like we don’t need to get to the station more than 30 mins before the departure for Ouigo according to this site though? https://www.sncf-connect.com/en-en/help/boarding-train

The signage is not great once you leave the station, so bring a map or prepare well with streetview.

Note that on your way back it's reversed: passport control for both French and UK borders is done at Gare du Nord. So, in both directions, you clear both borders on the side you are departing from.

Got it, thank you!

On the Eurostar side, indeed, there are no border nor customs checks on arrival. (I have done this trip a couple dozen times over the past two years, and have never been stopped by anyone upon disembarking in Paris).
For Ouigo, however, boarding usually closes 5 to 10 minutes before departure. Moreover it is wise to arrive a bit earlier than that, as they need to check everyone's ticket before boarding and sometimes a big queue forms. They suggest 30min; from experience this is overkill - 15min is usually plenty.
From Gare du Nord to Gare de l'Est, it is indeed a short-ish walk: about 500m from concourse to concourse, but more like 1km from your Eurostar carriage to the Ouigo platform. Unfortunately the Eurostar platforms are as far from Gare de l'Est as they can be, and walking the length of the platform also takes quite a bit of time (sometimes the crowd slows you down a little). Pay attention to your carriage number in Eurostar: if it is closer to 18 you are lucky, if it closer to 1 you have the whole platform to walk.
The walk between the stations has recently been somewhat upgraded, with an escalator and a lift added. See https://www.seat61.com/changing-stations-in-paris.htm#how-to-walk-from-paris-nord-to-paris-est for further details.
So, overall: in my opinion this connection is absolutely doable, with a margin that is not huge, but that is still moderately comfortable.

Thank you!! We’re in Coach 14, so it seems like we should be ok? 16 seems to be the farthest one in front for this train.

Yes, indeed, you are in luck! (Unless they swap the trainset at the last minute - which sometimes happens. In this case you might end up somewhere between Coach 7 and Coach 12, as the old e300 train sets have first-class seating in the middle.)

Gotcha, thanks so much. Think we should still be fine even if we’re in between Coaches 7-12? We’re planning to speed walk between Gare du Nord to Gare de l'Est anyways, but just making sure there wouldn’t be any risk. It seems from looking online that Ouigo may or may not honor any Rail Team requirement to put us on the next train if we miss the connection due to a Eurostar delay? We’re just trying to figure out if we should get to Paris the previous day to completely avoid any issues for peace of mind, since we have a week of travel afterwards contingent on getting to Strasbourg on time :)

If you need to be in Strasbourg on time, you should take some more buffer. While the connection is indeed quick, delays and cancellations do happen, especially at that time of the year (snow and/or storms could disrupt travel), and additionally rebooking on a different train (in case of cancellation or missed connection) may be difficult during such a busy period.

Well, zero risk does not exist :-) With your current plan, I would say you have somewhere between 95% and 98% chance of making your connection. It is then up to you to judge whether this is good enough for you!

Regarding RailTeam agreements: indeed, things are not very clear in this respect. If your train does end up late, you should by all means TRY to ask if they can rebook you at no charge. Success is possible, but not guaranteed. (Ouigo is a low-cost service, so they generally try to get away with as little customer service as they can. I have never been in this specific situation, though, so I have no first-hand experience to offer.)

Regarding position within the train: in the worst case, you can always walk to the front of the train just before it arrives. (But here, honestly, if the Eurostar is running on time, I think even starting from Coach 7 you should normally make it.)

So so helpful—thank you so much!
